# Windows 10 - Continue where I left off cannot be disabled

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/82752-turn-off-cortana-pick-up-where-i-left-off-windows-10-a.html) to disable the feature as much as possible (there are no "skills" to manage), but every time I turn my computer on I still have to wait for it to relaunch applications I had open when I turned it off last.

[image: Cortana setting has no effect]

Comment: You may want to read that tutorial again. It's doing something else. Since v1709, Microsoft added a "feature" where programs are launched after you restart based on what it thinks was running the last time. This annoying feature can't easily be disabled, but if you use the cmd command `shutdown -s -hybrid -t 0` it will not save these programs. I made a .cmd file and use that to shut down my computer until microsoft finally solves this ridiculous feature that no one wants.

Comment: @LPChip, that could be an answer, brief as it is.

Comment: My previous computer which was upgraded from Windows 7 was not doing that (including v1709) so there must be some way to fix it.
@LPChip thanks.

Comment: I kept the old drive, so if somebody could point me to suspect registry locations I could try and compare the hives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the sign-in option to automatically finish setting up my device after an update or restart.

[image: Unrelated setting]

Comment: ...which does not apply to domain accounts, yet they still restarts programs that register themselves. Are you sure this actually solved your problem? Try with programs like Microsoft Office or Task Manager. Not all software calls [RegisterApplicationRestart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373347(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I have not had task manager or Chrome reopen on its own since making this, and only this, setting change.